# Modifying attributes of items as they are dropped into a sortable list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a list of items that are draggable from a source list to a destination list contained in a form element. This works fine for one destination list as the 'name' attribute can be specified statically. However, I'm trying to figure out a way to support multiple destination lists, and I thought that if I could grab the ID from the destination list and dynamically add that as the name attribute to an input field as it is dropped into the sortable list, each list could be submitted as a separate array. My sortable, draggable, and droppable functions are working exactly the way I want them to with the following code:

```
    <div>
      Available Items
      <ul id="avail">
        <li><input type="hidden" name="options[]" value="1">Option 1</li>
        <li><input type="hidden" name="options[]" value="2">Option 2</li>
        <li><input type="hidden" name="options[]" value="3">Option 3</li>
        <li><input type="hidden" name="options[]" value="4">Option 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <p class="clear"></p>
    <form action="myForm.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div style="float:left;">
        List #1
        <ul class="sortable" id="list1">
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div style="float:left;margin-left:5px;">
        List #2
        <ul class="sortable" id="list2">
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div><br>
    </form>
```

and the following jQuery:

```
    $('#avail li').draggable({
      connectToSortable: ".sortable",
      helper: "clone",
      opacity: 0.75,
    });
    var sortableIn;
    $('.sortable').sortable({
      receive: function(event, ui) {
        sortableIn = 1;
      },
      over: function(event, ui) {
        sortableIn = 1;
      },
      out: function(event, ui) {
        sortableIn = 0;
      },
      beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
        if (sortableIn == 0) {
          ui.item.remove();
        }
      }
    }).droppable({
      greedy: true
    });
```

You can see it in action on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zo13gc8/5/). So to summarize based on this example, I'm trying to replace 'option[]' with either 'list1[]' or 'list2[]' as the name attribute of the input field when an option is dropped into one of these lists.

I assume I'd need to use something like attr('name',$(this).attr('id')) in the "receive" function or in a "drop" function but I'm not exactly sure where to put it and how to define the input field as the target of the attr() change instead of the containing `<li>`.

---

**RESOLUTION:**
I changed the `receive` function to `update` and added Twisty's second code snippet to it so that it now looks like:

```
update: function(event, ui) {
   sortableIn = 1;
   ui.item.find("input").attr("name", $(this).attr("id") + '[]');
}
```

Comment: We don't do "RESOLVED" in the titles here. If you found your own answer, either delete your question or answer it below and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the head's up. This was my first time posting on SO. Although, the relevancy of your comment could have been improved by noticing that an answer had already been provided and accepted below.

Comment: I am totally against deleting your question if it is resolved.  If you had a difficult issue, there's a good chance another will, and finding this will help them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put it in the `data-list` attribute of the destination element. For example:

```
<ul class="sortable" id="list1" data-list="1">
</ul>

<ul class="sortable" id="list2" data-list="2">
</ul>
```

Then in `receive`, you can assign the value you want to the `name` attribute:

```
ui.item.find("input").attr("name", "list" + $(this).data("list") + "[]");
```

Or you could read the ID:

```
ui.item.find("input").attr("name", $(this).attr("id") + "[]");
```

This will result in the received item of having either:

```
name="list1[]"
name="list2[]"
```

Since `$(this)` will be the sortable list the element was dragged to, it will get assigned the list number from the data.

Comment: YES! It was the "find("input")" that I was missing. I had to add it to both the receive function and over function to get it to work every time, but that did the trick!

Comment: @KenC great. Yes, `ui.item` was the `<li></li>` element, so we had to find the `input` within it to change that attribute.

Comment: Actually I just tested it a bit more and it works perfectly when it's ONLY in the over function instead of the receive function for some reason. Not sure I understand why that would be, but hey...it works :) FWIW when it was in the receive function and not in the over function, the very first time I would drop a particular option it would still have name="options[]" and then the second time I'd drop the same option it would be correct. Also every once in a while it would seemingly randomly (though probably not) put name="list2[]" on items dropped in list1 and vice versa.

Comment: @KenC without testing, I suspect that `ui.item` works in `over`, where `ui.helper` might be the object to work with in `receive`. Again, I didn't test it; just based off my own experience.

Comment: @KenC I have also had better luck in `update` versus `receive`.